# Bad model fit for a second-order growth curve with time-varying covariates. Do I have to find a way out or will it depend on the aim of the analysis?

Tags: panel-data, structural-equation-modeling, time-varying-covariate, growth-model

I am running a second-order latent growth curve model with seven repeated measures.
I have 2 time-invariant covariates (TIC, country and sex) and 2 time-varying covariates
(TVC, both are latent variables (5 items each), seven repeated measures).
All of the variables were measured at the same time.

I have already run an unconditional linear growth curve with my focal variable, let's say, A.
The fit is good for this model.
Later I ran a conditional model with the TICs. The fit decreased but was still good.

However, when I added the TVC, variables B and C, the model did not fit.
(I did not add both at the same time. One by one as separate models)
I understand that it means that both of the variables shifted their corresponding value
of variable A in such a way that it does not fit a line anymore.

My first question is, if the aim of the analysis for the model with TVC is to see how much
they shift the value of A in a certain direction, is it plausible to make an argument
that "the model no longer fits a linear trajectory owing to the effects of the TVCs" and
not respecify the model to make it fit? (or find a better-fitting model)

My second question is, does the worse fit for a linear model indicate that the effects of the TVC on variable A are inconsistent? I am assuming that if the effects of the TVC on variable A are constant, a linear trajectory should still fit.

I have a wald test code in my syntax to test this (I saw it in a textbook) but am not really sure how it works or if it is applicable here. Below is the syntax. (I use Mplus)

```
    AE1 ON AS1(P1);
    AE2 ON AS2(P2);
    AE3 ON AS3(P3);
 model test:
   P1=P2; P2=P3;
```

*Note. AE is my focal variable and AS is one of my TVC. The numbers following them indicate wave of data collection.*

Thanks to everyone in advance who gave a thought to this post.

Answer (score 1):

The misfit when you add additional variables with multiple indicators can have many reasons (especially in a complex model like yours), including problems with the measurement model (e.g., correlated error terms within or across constructs, cross-loadings). It is impossible to say what the reasons are without conducting a thorough analysis of your model, data, and results. Examining model residuals and/or modification indices can sometimes be helpful to locate the sources of misfit.

Comment: I see... this tells me that I need a closer look at my results. Thank you for pointing out some points to look at. Does your answer mean that I cannot interpret the model with bad fit (as is) when my aim is to see the effects of the TVC on each time point?

Comment: I would be hesitant to interpret any parameter estimates in a misspecified (not well fitting) model because the estimates may be biased.